# Asymptotical behavior of $a_n$ with several properties.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume $a_n$ is infinite sequence. We know $a_n>0$, $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=1+\frac{p}{n}+c_n$ and $\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty|c_n|$ converges. I want to prove that $a_n$ is asymptotically the same as $\frac{d}{n^p}$ for some non-zero $d$.

It is easy to see that $a_n = \frac{a_1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n 1+ \frac{p}{k} + c_k}$. I also know and proved that asymptotically ${(1+\frac{1}{n})}^p$ is the same as $1 + \frac{p}{n} + \frac{d_n}{n^2}$ where $d_n$ is bounded. I feel it somehow can be used here, but I do not see how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Let $b_n=a_n n^p$ then we have

$$\ln b_{n}-\ln b_{n+1}=\ln\left(\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}\right)-p\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=c_n+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
so by telescoping we see that the sequence $(\ln b_n)$ is convergent to say $\ell$ so $(b_n)$ is convergent to  $d=e^{\ell}>0$ and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks, it looks almost perfect, however I do not understand what and why you did with $\frac{d_n}{n^2}$ term. Can you please explain this?

Comment: We wrote the term $\frac{d_n}{n^2}$ where $d_n$ is bounded on the form $\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$.

Comment: I see it :) I do not understand why this term can not break convergence of $\ln b_n$

Comment: Because $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.